# How to get value of inner arrays Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have the following array in angularjs and want to populate the Select List.

```
types: {
  data: {
    result: [
      {
        Item: Default Group
        Val: 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the following code but no result

```
<div ng-controller="dtaCtrl">
   <select class="form-control" ng-repeat="lop in types">
      <option>{{lop.data.result.Item}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: It **sounds** like you're looking for `{{lop.result[0].Item}}`. That's assuming you truly want `lop` to be equivalent to `data`...

Comment: types is not an array, so using ng-repeat to iterate on types doesn't make much sense. `lop.data.result` **is** an array, and an array doesn't have an Item property, so `lop.data.result.Item` doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat needs to be an array - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

try:

```
vm.types = [{
            data: {
                result:
                   [{
                      Item: 'Default Group',
                      Val: 1
                   }]
                 }
           }];
```

And then use:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-repeat="lop in vm.types track by $index">
    <option>{{lop.data.result[$index].Item}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dear friend: I am getting this data from a web service I designed. In last example I had made a mistake after setting it up, I got the following result, Yet it is not producing the output;

Comment: types:  { 
data: [{"Item":"Default Group","Val":"1"}]
status: 200
headers: null
config:  { 
method: POST .........................

Comment: The problem with the repeat is that `types` is not an array. If you want to repeat just the inner array, can you do `ng-repeat="lop in types.data` and bind to `{{lop.Item}}`